# Continuous infiniti

Tags: infinitives, continuous-aspect

I can’t remember seeing the same man as devoted to anything as he is **to serving you**. When to use to +verb ing form ?

Comment: This isn’t an infinitive; it’s a prepositional phrase with a gerund as the object of the preposition “to.”

Comment: He is devoted to serving you. She was opposed to drinking alcohol. He was addicted to smoking. They are committed to helping the blind. But also He is devoted to his wife. She was opposed to capital punishment. He was addicted to heroin. They are committed to their cause. The relevant strings here are 'be devoted / committed / opposed / addicted / ... to' taking an ing-form **or** a regular noun.